# Form inside <tr> doesn't work

Tags: html, forms, html-table

I have a little problem here.. I have a form and I write it inside a table content, but it doesn't work.. so let me show you my code:

```
<table>
<form name='editpo' method=POST action='js_buat_po.php?act=caricustomer&doit=update&uid=$data[uid]'>
<tr bgcolor=$warna>
<td><input type=hidden name='iddemand' value='$data[id_demand]'>$data[barcode]</td><td><input type='text' name='nama' value='$data[nama_item]'></td>
<td>$data[id_pr]</td>
<td align=right><input type='text' name='jumlah' value='$data[jumlah]'></td>
<td align=right><input type='text' name='regane' id='regane' value='$data[hargabeli]'></td>
<td align=right>".number_format($total,0,',','.')."</td>
<td align=right> <input type=submit value='UPDATE'></form><a href='js_buat_po.php?act=caricustomer&doit=hapus&uid=$data[uid]'>Hapus</a></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

And when I try check the output from inspect element.. I got something like this:

```
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <form name="editpo" method="POST" action="js_buat_po.php?act=caricustomer&amp;doit=update&amp;uid=7"></form>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="iddemand" value="2">accesories204</td><td><input type="text" name="nama" value="  AC komplit Mitsubishi Pick Up C. T120 / 2012 merk sanden   "></td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td align="right"><input type="text" name="jumlah" value="1"></td>
                        <td align="right"><input type="text" name="regane" id="regane" value="5000000"></td>
            <td align="right">5.000.000</td>
            <td align="right"> <input type="submit" value="UPDATE"><a href="js_buat_po.php?act=caricustomer&amp;doit=hapus&amp;uid=7">Hapus</a></td>
                        </tr>
```

I don't know why my code become like this, any help please?

====UPDATE============

So how to do like this,
I have 1 table and dynamic which the data per tr is different, so lets say I wont to use update button per tr.. and how to create an array id for my tr identifier?

The format is like this..

```
<form>
<table>
<tr id='1'><td><input type='text' name='tes' value='xxx'></td><td><input type='submit' value='update'></td></tr>  <--- Submit the data from tr1
<tr id='2'><td><input type='text' name='tes' value='xxx'></td><td><input type='submit' value='update'></td></tr>  <--- Submit the data from tr2
</table>
</form>
```

How to do that? Can anyone  help me?

Comment: First, fix your html. You cannot embed a form inside a table like that. The form tags should be OUTSIDE the table. Plus, you're obviously building this form with PHP, so show the actual PHP code.

Comment: why cant you add <form name='editpo' method=POST...... line before <table> start and end the form </form> after </table>.. also you have two form end tags</form>

Comment: because i have dynamic <tr> , so i want use the form to update the content per <tr>.. any idea?

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the need to put the entire table in the form. Also, you should use `id` attributes as identifiers for the inputs rather than `name`.

Comment: i've already update my question.. can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Format at worst should be

```
<form>
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
               <input ....>
          <td>
          <td>
               <input type=submit value='UPDATE'>
          <td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

In reply to your update: Looks like you need two forms:

```
<table>
     <tr>
          <td>
                <form ...>
                    <input..><input type=submit>
                </form>
          </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td>
               <form ...>
                    <input..><input type=submit>
               </form>
          </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```